# Converting a Riemann Sum into a definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Question:
Find $\lim_{n \to  ∞}$  $(1+2^{0.5} + ..... n^{0.5})/n^{3/2}$

I have made this the sum from $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n {k^{0.5}\over n^{3/2}}$ and want to make this a definite integral, however it is not of the form needed for this process normally. Do I let $\Delta x = 1/n^{3/4}$? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Write $n^{3/2} = n \cdot n^{0.5}$ and take another look.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the summation as following $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n {k^{0.5}\over n^{3/2}}={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n ({k\over n})^{0.5}$$and proceed by taking $f(x)=\sqrt x$.

Comment: I thought of this, but what confused me is that in the formula I was looking at, you had to have $f[a+ $\Delta x] $\Delta x,$ but the power of $n$ is not the same in this case?

Comment: Actually, it should be $f(a+k\Delta x)\Delta x$ since we are summing up surfaces of adjacent rectangles of width $\Delta x$ and height $f(a+k\Delta x)$. Now take $f(x)=\sqrt x$, $a=0$ and $\Delta x={1\over n}$